# Installation of kissmetrics for a website with different environments (DEV/INT/PROD)

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-mvc-5, kissmetrics

I would like to use kissmetrics for my website (in MVC 5 asp.net) deployed on Azure.

I have several configurations for my website, one for each environment (debug, integration and production).

I have the JS for to use kissmetrics in the layout. My problem is that metrics are computed whatever the environment is (debug, production ..).
I would like to have metrics computed only for the production environment.

How to do that correctly ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want [create a new site](http://support.kissmetrics.com/how-tos/create-site.html) for each instance. Each site has its own API key and tracking code. From the linked docs:

> You can generate more than one API key for your KISSmetrics account if you’re managing different websites, or if you want to keep your testing/development data separate from your production site’s data.